# Seeing this error in console log using ngxs store. "Error ocurred while serializing the store value, value not updated"

Tags: session, angular8, store, datastore, ngxs

**Affected Package**
The issue is caused by package @ngxs/storage-plugin/fesm5/ngxs-storage-plugin.js

**Description**

```
I am using ngxs store in my angular application for storage management. Recently I am seeing below weird console error in my browser when I switch between various angular components while dispatching action to store
'Error ocurred while serializing the store value, value not updated.'

I tried to explore on this but there is no proper documentation available over the internet on this.
```

**Exception or Error**

```
ngxs-storage-plugin.js:288 Error ocurred while serializing the store value, value not updated.
(anonymous) @ ngxs-storage-plugin.js:288
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._next @ tap.js:45
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:53
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/ReplaySubject.js.ReplaySubject._subscribe @ ReplaySubject.js:67
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject._trySubscribe @ Subject.js:89
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
shareReplayOperation @ shareReplay.js:42
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call @ tap.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchOperator.call @ catchError.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call @ tap.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
shareReplayOperation @ shareReplay.js:30
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/@ngxs/store/fesm5/ngxs-store.js.InternalDispatcher.dispatch @ ngxs-store.js:1751
dispatch @ ngxs-store.js:2108
```

**Libs:**

```
@angular/core version: "~8.2.14",
@ngxs/devtools-plugin: "^3.7.0",
@ngxs/logger-plugin: "^3.6.2-dev.master-eaa5d86",
@ngxs/storage-plugin: "^3.7.0",
@ngxs/store: "^3.7.0",
```

*Same issue with 3.6.2-dev version also.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the source code for the error: https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/2b6b81823e31f7c3d6835f4b0bec70364cb734c7/packages/storage-plugin/src/storage.plugin.ts#L62

They left this note:

```
// Caretaker note: we have still left the `typeof` condition in order to avoid
// creating a breaking change for projects that still use the View Engine.
```

Looks like you need to opt in to Ivy, and get off the View Engine perhaps. Here's the latest documentation for Ivy: https://angular.io/guide/ivy and if you are on version 8 of Angular: https://v8.angular.io/guide/ivy